Selenium Java WebDriver - How to fetch the URL of User's Home page after Successful login?
I am new to the Selenium Tools and developing JEE9 application using JSF Pages. While writing the Integration Test in Java (after recording using Selenium IDE) - I could not figure out how can I fetch the User's Home page after the successful login:
Below is my test code:
driver.get("http://localhost:8080/<app-name>/");
driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1850, 1053));
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Log In")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("<correct email>");
driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("<correct password>");
driver.findElement(By.id("logInBtn")).click();   

I the actual scenario on the Browser (and after the login success),the application redirects to User's home page:
http://localhost:8080/<app-name>/userHome.xhtml

My question is how can I simulate the same behaviour in my test case?
I have search the Internet in vain along with going through the WebDriver API.

Just wait for the URL to change and then continue your test. See What is the best way to check URL change with Selenium in Python?. But I do seriously hope you're not using XHTML but normal HTML with the appropriate doctype, because XHTML stopped being "a thing you use on the web" quite a while ago, having officially been retired in 2018 in favour of the HTML living standard, and having been "not a thing you use" much longer than that.

@Mike. Thanks for suggesting the html5 approach instead of XHTML, which I agree makes sense. Unfortunately, however I could not find much material on the web on HTML5 templates. Also, I have tried exploring Eclipse and Netbeans IDEs. They both generate .XHTML templates.

@mike. In the meantime could you please let me know how can I confirm if the URL has been changed? Thanks

See the post I linked you to, and find the answer that shows a wait_for_correct_current_url.

You can fetch the URL after login using the following code
System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());

